# Matlab difference between sum(A) and sum(sum(A))

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have two images `C` and `B` and I need to sum the total difference `A = C-B`.

Now, I got the solution `sum(A)`, but I also read that `sum(sum(A))` has also been used for a rating function. Can someone explain me what the difference is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `sum` sums over the first non-singleton dimension of the matrix.  A singleton dimension is one of size 1. So for a 2D matrix, it will sum over columns, yielding a row vector. Calling `sum` with this result will sum over the one row, yielding a single value.

Thus, `sum(sum(A))` is the sum over the full 2D matrix `A`.

The same can be done with `sum(A(:))`, or, in more recent versions of MATLAB, with `sum(A,'all')`.